# Does the graph of a continuous function have measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a continuous function from a closed interval in $\mathbb R$ to the euclidean space of dimension $n$, I can checked the result when $n=1$. but what if $n>1$? should I proceed by induction? I didn't learn the measure theory, but only the definition of the measure zero.

Remark: a set $A$ in the euclidean space is defined to have measure zero if for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, there exist a covering of $A$ by countable closed rectangles such that the sum of the volumes of them is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Any continuous function is uniformly continuous over any compact set $K$. It follows that the measure of the graph of a continuous function $f$ over $K$ is bounded by $\mu(K)\cdot\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number.

Comment: Well like i said, i don't know about the measure, but only the concept of the measure zero.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: how would you apply your argument to a Peano curve?

Comment: @MartinArgerami: the Peano curve is not a graph of a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you include your work on $n=1$? I don't see why it cannot be generalized to $n>1$

Comment: @John Ma: My work is just the same as this: http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~simic/Fall09/Math132/Homework/hw12.soln.pdf.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: it is a continuous function $[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$, which is exactly the situation the OP is asking about. If your argument works only for $n=1$, you should have said so (and maybe explain why).

Comment: @MartinArgerami : The question is asking for the measure of the graph, but not the measure of the image.

Comment: @JohnMa: you are right, my bad.

Comment: @Mathcho The answer linked is (probably) what Jack has in mind. That can be generalized. Did you try that?

Comment: @John Ma: Well no i haven't. i thought it will get fairly messy if i do it that way. So i was finding a way to do it by mathematical induction, if possible.

Comment: You may also use the following lemma: if $A$ is a measurable set with positive measure, $A-A=\{a_1-a_2:a_1,a_2\in A\}$ contains a neighbourhood of the origin. The graph $G$ of a function is obviously a measurable set, but obviously $G-G$ cannot contain any neighbourhood of the origin, hence its measure is zero.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: Thank you for your comment. But like i said, i haven't taught anything about the measure but only the concept of measure zero.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^n$ is continuous. Let $\epsilon>0.$ Because $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1],$ there exists $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $|y-x|\le 1/m \implies |f(y)-f(x)| \le \epsilon.$ Let $C$ be the $n$-cube $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]^n.$ Note that $C$ contains $\{x \in \mathbb R^n: |x|\le \epsilon \}.$ It follows that the graph of $f$ is contained in

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^m \,[(k-1)/m,k/m] \times (f(k/m) + C).$$

The sum of the volumes of these $(n+1)$-dimensional rectangles is

$$m\cdot (\frac{1}{m}(2\epsilon)^n) = (2\epsilon)^n.$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small, the graph of $f$ has measure $0$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}.$

Comment: What do you mean by epsilonC?

Comment: I edited my answer slightly. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thank you. but What is f(k/m)+C , the sum of coordinate and a set? Hope i am not being too stupid here.

Comment: $f(k/m)$ is a point in $\mathbb R^n,$ so $f(k/m) + C$ is just $C$ translated by $f(k/m).$ I.e, it's the $\epsilon$ cube centered at $f(k/m).$